# Echo a variable in a variable

Tags: php

I'm loading a variable from a file, then I need to echo that variable based on another on page variable. Here is the code

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'states-desc/before_after_table_description.php';
ob_end_clean();
echo $alabama_after;
?>
```

Now, I need to replace the echo **$alabama_after** with **$state_name_after**.

Okay, so when the variable already loaded on top page is **$state_name**. That state name is say florida. when I drop **$state_name_before**; I need the variable to become $florida_before and echo the content of include file variable $florida_before;.

If any way I can drop a variable name within a variable?

Comment: `I need to replace the echo $alabama_after with $state_name_after.` -- What do you mean by that?

Comment: I think he wants `${"state_{$name}_after"}`

Comment: on a side note.. i have no idea what your include looks like or your general code structure, but you may almost certainly be able to do things more easily by putting your states in some kind of array structure instead of having individually hardcoded variables for states..

Answer (score 2):

Are you maybe looking for something like [`eval()`](http://www.php.net/eval)?

Comment: While this might solve the immediate issue, I try to avoid using `eval` if at all possible; it opens up some very dangerous security holes in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need "variable variables".

I tested the following with PHP 5.3.26.

File i.php:

```
<?php
$alabama_after = "montgomery";
```

File p.php:

```
<?php

ob_start();
include "i.php";
ob_clean();

$state_name = "alabama";

$state_name_after = "{$state_name}_after";

// the following two echo the same thing:
echo $alabama_after . "\n";
echo $$state_name_after . "\n";
```

Output:

```
$ php p.php
montgomery
montgomery
```

See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

---

I'm wondering, however, why you are using this method when you could use an associative array. For example, i.php could look like this:

```
<?php
$after_data = array(
  "alabama" => "montgomery"
);
```

And p.php could look like this:

```
<?php

ob_start();
include "i.php";
ob_clean();

$state_name = "alabama";

$state_name_after = $after_data[$state_name];

echo $state_name_after . "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but for some reason when I do `$state_name` I get `alabama`. When I do `$alabama_after`, I get the text from include file, but `$$state_name_after` doesn't echo the variable I need. It's just blank space in page, no errors, even after running `$state_name_after = "{$state_name}_after";` before. Odd

Comment: I tested it to make sure. See edits above. I also suggest an alternative way of organizing your data.

Comment: thanks again. I still get a blank page, no errors on echo. I'm not sure if something in php settings needs to be changed. I'm going to put that data in DB with the rest. BTW, I was using this method as I'm comfortable with editing includes and formatting it instead of having to go to DB everytime. I didn't build an admin area to edit as the data will be there for a while unchanged.